# How to change this javascript code to show a modified image?

Tags: javascript, color-thief

I am playing with image color quantization algorithms. I have found this link

[Color Thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief)

where a javascript (a language that I have never studied) implementation of a modified median cut algorithm is presented. But the demo shows just the ten dominant colors.

I would like to see what the quantized image looks like. In the file `src/color-thief.js` (line 132), there is a call to the quantization function. This functions returns a `CMap object`, which can be used to extract the dominant colors and to map a color to the best one in the reduced color palette. Given the CMap object, how do I modify the original image and show it?

### Edit 1

This question is not about color quantization algorithms, but what i need to change in the Color Thief project in order to show a modified image. Suppose that, when i click the 'Click' button, i want to show the image after adding to all its pixels the value 10.

Comment: What do you want to show? A palette? A dominant color?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer I want to change every pixel color of the original image with the nearest color of the reduced palette and show the modified (quantized) image. I know i have to use the CMap map function on the pixel array of the original image, but i do not know how to show it again.

Comment: I'm not into color quantization algorithms, but I assume you want to simplify colors of a picture to nearest of this palette?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer Yes, the concept is: map every RGB color to the nearest color of a subset of the RGB cube. This is what that project does. But, since i know nothing about javascript, html, canvas and so on, i do not know how to show the quantized (modified) image. There must be a way to change the pixels and show it again..

Comment: I provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I made this just for you.

I assume you want to *simplify* colors of an image to its palette provided by `color-thief`.

To achieve this I used [color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) and [nearest-color](https://github.com/dtao/nearest-color).

Basically, you want to generate a color-thief's palette, then loop each pixel and get a closest palette value compared to the color of this pixel.

Check out this solution on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpvGjr), code below:

```
/* rgbToHex() and leadingZero() functions ripped from nearest-color. */
function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  return '#' + leadingZero(rgb.r.toString(16)) +
     leadingZero(rgb.g.toString(16)) + leadingZero(rgb.b.toString(16));
}

function leadingZero(value) {
  if (value.length === 1) value = '0' + value;   
  return value;
}

/* Initialize an image and the canvas. */
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

/* When the image is loaded */
img.onload = function(){

  /* Initialize color-thief and get a palette from image. */
  var colorthief = new ColorThief(); 
  var colorthief_palette = colorthief.getPalette(img, 8);
  var palette = {};

  /* Turn color-thief palette to nearest-color-compatible palette. */
  for(var i = 0; i < colorthief_palette.length; i++){
    var r = colorthief_palette[i][0];
    var g = colorthief_palette[i][1]; 
    var b = colorthief_palette[i][2];
    var o = {r: r, g: g, b: b};
    palette["color_" + i] = rgbToHex(o);
  }

  /* Initialize nearest-color */
  var clr = nearestColor.from(palette);

  /* Initialize canvas, draw the image data and hide the default image. */
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  img.style.display = "none"; 

  var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var pixel = data.data;

  /* Loop for each pixel of image. */
  for (var i = 0, n = pixel.length; i < n; i += 4) {

      var r = pixel[i+0];
      var g = pixel[i+1]; 
      var b = pixel[i+2];
      var o = {r: r, g: g, b: b};
      var color = rgbToHex(o);
      var nearest = clr(color);

      pixel[i+0] = nearest.rgb.r;
      pixel[i+1] = nearest.rgb.g;
      pixel[i+2] = nearest.rgb.b;


  } 

  ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);

}
```

In result, this image:

[image]

Becomes this image:
[image]

Comment: @MarcoMasci Nope.

Comment: @MarcoMasci I'll add a button, hold on

Comment: @MarcoMasci Use "do it" button on top to transform the image.

Comment: That is really what i needed! Thank you! But i do not know how to change the image. How do you provided that image?

Comment: @MarcoMasci I used Data URI. Check out the HTML.

Comment: @MarcoMasci Make sure to upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the content of the page.
But if I understand correctly what you do, you should start studying jQuery to manipulate events (checks, animations, etc.) of images.

[enter link description here](https://jquery.com/)

this is an example that i found with jquery for 'color thief'

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/roundedbygravity/8231471)

Comment: this should rather be a comment

Comment: i cant' write comment, i'm just registered in stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Better to wait on real answers to get points to post comments than to post a comment as an answer.  Or just log on for a few days in a row, mark something helpful, etc.  The first few badges are very easy.